# Problems when Manipulating viewpoint of Graphics3D[cube]

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, manipulate, dynamic, options

I wanted to `Manipulate` the `ViewPoint` of `Grphics3D[Cube[]]`.

My codes are

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[Cube[], ViewPoint -> {a, b, c},
  BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> Small],
 {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {c, -1, 1}, Alignment -> Center,
 ContentSize -> {250, 250}, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

But I have 2 problems

Problem 1) Some boundary parts of the cube are cut off when rotated.
I tried many options for `Manipulate` like `ContentSize`,`ImageMargins`,`FrameMargins,`... but didn't work. See the former part of the attached Gif image.

Problem 2) If the cube is rotated by mouse-clicking the cube itself(just once), then the slider doesn't work any more. See the latter part of the attached Gif image.

Thank you[image]

My mathematica is V 12.2 and OS is windows 10, and I get

```
SystemInformation["Devices", "ConnectedDisplays"]

{{"Region" -> {{0., 1152.}, {0., 615.6}}, 
  "FullRegion" -> {{0., 1152.}, {0., 648.}}, 
  "PixelDimensions" -> {1920, 1080}, "BitDepth" -> 32, 
  "Resolution" -> 120., "Scale" -> 1.66667}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is possible that it is not because of the version issue. And I believe there is a way to control (show all, never cut off) the margin of the content.

Comment: Oh,  a user commented that my code works well in mathematica v13, but the comment was deleted a few seconds ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not getting the first issue you mention on V 13.1 no cut off. But add `SphericalRegion->True` as it is a good option to always use.

[image]

For the second one, try adding this

```
ViewPoint -> Dynamic@{a, b, c}
```

So the code becomes

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[Cube[], ViewPoint -> Dynamic@{a, b, c},
  BoxRatios -> 1,
  ImageSize -> Small,
  SphericalRegion->True
  ],
 {a, -1, 1},
 {b, -1, 1},
 {c, -1, 1},
 Alignment -> Center,
 ContentSize -> {250, 250},
 ControlPlacement -> Top,
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b, c}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! 2nd problem was solved completely, but 1st problem is not solved though I applied `SphericalRegion->True`. When I test it on mathematica v13, I will update my comment!

Comment: It works nicely after updating to v13.